# How can I use Cassandra database with CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cassandra, cakephp-2.3, cassandra-2.0

I want to know how can I configure the database with a CakePHP application.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported by the framework by default nor is it in the [database driver repository](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources).

You'll have to write your own driver class. See the code of any of the existing drivers, Mysql for example for a reference.